# Are chrestomathy style requests acceptable?

Tags: discussion, overview-questions

I was thinking about a class of real questions that are really answerable here, in the overview style and that's something like what is asked for on http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code. This would be tantamount to asking for the views of each tradition that takes a stance on a particular issue, like an overview question – but in a concise way.  Answers would *have* to include written, authoritative viewpoints, not "I'm an Evangelical and this is how Evangelicals read the Bible" type answers.

This apparently is called a [chrestomathy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrestomathy), and I think we could use a tag [crestomathy-request](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crestomathy-request) (as opposed to [crestomathy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crestomathy), which would be a meta-tag) to denote this kind of a question.

---

At the very least, I'd like to get [my first question unclosed](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-do-various-christian-denominations-believe-the-meaning-of-life-is). FWIW, given the criteria for what an "overview question" is, I think it's topical now.

Comment: Is this sort of what such an answer would look like? [Is God's sovereignty a term associated with Reformed theology?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/55938/21576)

Comment: @Nathaniel yes, that's exactly what I'd like to see - those kinds of answers are very helpful!

Comment: These are already on-topic. I guess I'd just recommend bolding the requirement of quotes for each viewpoint.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a subset of the "overview" question type, so I'd say they're generally on-topic. However...

- Some "overview" questions, particularly ones asking for the views of all of Christendom, are still too broad.  It may be worth specifying a particular subset of Christendom.
- I don't really like the idea of a separate tag for these.  If anything, we should have an "overview-request" tag first.  But either seems like a meta tag to me.
- Also, keep in mind that we generally don't enforce *how* people answer questions.  Some time ago I tried to figure out [what “Not An Answer” really means](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5701/21576), and the short version is that questioners can't resort to NAA flags whenever answers don't meet their specifications.  So I can't say "All answers to this question must be exactly 500 characters long" and then flag any violators. Similarly, answers that don't actually follow the chrestomathy format, but are still kinda sorta overviews, according to current practice wouldn't qualify for NAA flags.

So to conclude: I like it. Let's give it a try.

Comment: I think that if a question is asking for quotes, that if answers don't give any quotes that's a valid NAA

Comment: @curiousdannii I think the community would agree with that.  But if the quotes are longer than expected, or some quotes are missing, etc., it becomes more doubtful.