# Is there any way to make a denomination-agnostic question on-topic without the old trick of turning it into an overview question?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently asked [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79959/what-is-an-overview-of-how-denominations-interpret-the-expressions-born-again). If you check the edit history, my question was originally intended to be denomination-agnostic, i.e., open to answers from any Christian denomination. However, that's seen as off-topic, so it got closed. In order to salvage it, I did what I've already done with several questions in the past: I quickly edited it to turn it into an overview question, and, voila, the question got re-opened as expected. That's great, but as an undesirable side effect, people are now perceiving the question as way too tedious because no one is willing to put in the effort of investigating the viewpoints of all major branches of Christianity. Instead, folks usually prefer to post answers based on their own personal perspectives, which they naturally feel more comfortable with.

Is there any way to make a denomination-agnostic question on-topic without turning it into an overview question (or more generally, without making it overwhelming and tedious for people to answer)?

Comment: I really like the concept of overview question, but in practice they do turn out to be really hard to answer, and for a lot of them we end up being pretty soft of the rules and allow answers that only present part of the Christian world. So I'm all ears if anyone has new ideas for how to improve this site's overview questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two other tricks.

1. [Crestomathy](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6499/are-chrestomathy-style-requests-acceptable) requests which are a targeted type of overview question where you're specifically asking for texts from various sources supporting an idea (these are basically overview questions)
2. [biblical-basis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblical-basis) Biblical basis questions assume a Biblical Truth which may only be held by a subset of denominations, you don't have to spell out which denominations in particular hold that doctrine, but it should be relatively obvious.

But no there's no getting around it specifically because we don't let the answers devolve into a competition where the most appealing answer rises to the top.  We only want the correct answers to rise to the top and this is impossible if you don't have a frame of reference by which to judge the rightness underlying the answer other than subjectivity.

Comment: Isn't biblical-basis without mentioning a denomination just an overview question in disguise, maybe slightly more focused but still overview because interpretation of the Bible differs considerably between denominations?

Comment: @kutschkem practically speaking, I think it is more [tag:denomination-oblivious] than [tag:denomination-agnostic]